# What is a nice synonym for "significant other" in Italian, except "partner" and "amore"?

Tags: word-meaning, word-choice, synonym

I am looking for something more desirable than *partner* or *amore* in Italian. Of course *amore* is nice but it translates to love, but to say more indirect, is there anything else?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe an expressions closer to "significant other" might be "*la mia metà*" (literally "my [other] half") or the variations "*la mia metà migliore*" ("my better half") and "*la mia dolce metà*" ("my sweet/lovely [other] half").
Those expressions are most commonly used to refer to the husband/wife but they are used also by unmarried couples, sometimes (but not necessarily) with a slightly humorous or ironic intent.

Comment: These expressions are very nice, but personally I only ever heard them jokingly or in old films.

Comment: Hi @DaG. I agree those expression might sound a bit old-fashioned (although not so much old-fashioned to sound odd) but, on other hand, the problem with using "*compagna/o*" (or "*ragazza/o*" or "*fidanzata/o*") is that the aim of "significant other" is not to infer anything about the marital status **nor** the gender identity while "*compagna/o*" an other similar expressions are not gender neutral.

Comment: I see your point, secan. I find it hopeless, at present, to achieve gender-neutrality in Italian. Even if one were to mention their SO as _la mia metà_, the problem is back as soon as they mention their job, or use an adjective or a pronoun, some verbal forms (_è andata/o_) and so on. Then again, if I talk about my SO, I know which gender they are or prefer to be considered.

Answer (score 3):

What one considers to be “nice” or “desirable” is of course highly subjective, but I find **compagna/o** the most usual and neutral-sounding word for a “significant other” (with whom one is not married). Other options include **ragazza/o** (more like “girlfriend/boyfriend”), which is most suitable for younger people, and **fidanzata/o**, literally meaning “betrothed”, but since few people get actually engaged, it's sometimes used for one's partner (and occasionally as an euphemism for a lover or some not-too-significant other).

Comment: I would say that *ragazza/o* is too informal and *fidanzato/a* has the implication that the partnership is serious (that "significant other" does not have). All things considered I think *compagna/o* is the best choice here.

Comment: @DenisNardin: I believe that all those connotations can vary quite a lot. From my experience, _compagna/o_ almost means “de facto spouse”, while _fidanzata/o_ can even refer, jokingly, to occasional partners. For _fidanzato_ both Treccani and Zingarelli speak of a _rapporto/relazione amorosa_ not necessarily connected with an actual engagement.

Comment: What about "la mia metà"?